# react-native: disable animations

Tags: animation, react-native

We are using `Animated` and `react-native-animatable` quite heavily and starting to notice slowness on some old devices. All animations set `useNativeDriver` which makes us believe that we may have a few too many animations.

Is there a way to overwrite the `Animated` prototype to completely disable animations? I looked into this and it didn't seem simple.

Another option I'm considering is to leave my fade animations in but set the initial value in the `constructor` to the final value. This approach definitely doesn't show any animations but would it also bypass the animation in the native bridge as the value isn't changing?

```
class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opacity: 1 // Notice how this is set to 1
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({opacity: 1})
    }, 1000)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Animatable.View style={{opacity}} easing='ease-in' transition='opacity' duration={500} useNativeDriver={true} />
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a wrapping component for it and use that instead of Animated.View

```
export default const AnimatedViewWrapper = (props) => {
   if (/* slow device check */) {
      return React.createElement(View, props)
   } else {
      return React.createElement(Animated.View, props)
   }
}
```

You might need to filter the props you receive because `View` does not have many of the props that `Animated.View` has. You can get them through View.propTypes. You might need to do this only if `__DEV__` is true as propTypes are stripped out in production builds